How can I make a list containing 5 rows and 10 columns from a list?
I have a list
list = RandomInteger[{10, 100}, 100]


I want to make a list containing 5 rows and 10 columns. I tried
mylist = list[[1 ;; 5, 1 ;; 10]]

I don't get the result. How can i get the result?

ArrayReshape[list, {5, 10}] should do it.  You would use list[[1 ;; 5, 1 ;; 10]] if your original list was 2D already.

Thank you very much. If I have list = RandomInteger[{10, 100}, {100, 20}] How can I do?

Your new list has 100 rows and 20 columns. If you want to make it 5 rows by 10 columns, then you have to decide which 5 rows and which 10 columns to pick. Right? Assuming you want the first 5 rows and first 10 columns, then now you can use list[[1 ;; 5, 1 ;; 10]]  but you can also do list[[2 ;; 6, 2 ;; 11]] and so on.

Thank you very much.

Take[ Partition[list, 5], 10] keeps the first 50 elements.
